# Jest unit test for function throw error is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

Hi I have a function something like this:

```
async function getDefault(productType: ProductType = ProductType.PERSONAL_DEFAULT): Promise<OfferProduct> {
  throw new Error('getDefault products/offers api is deprecated')
}
```

And I wish to test the throw out error string/value, so my test looks like this

```
    it('returns expected result (deprecated)', async () => {
    const ProductsSdk = reImportSdk()
    ProductsSdk.configure(config)  
    await expect(() => ProductsSdk.getDefault()).rejects.toThrow('getDefault products/offers api is deprecated');
  })
```

but however, this isn's working, in terminal console it is complaining about:

```
● getDefault › returns expected result (deprecated)

expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

Matcher error: received value must be a promise

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function anonymous]

  45 |     // const response = await ProductsSdk.getDefault()    
  46 |     // expect(() => ProductsSdk.getDefault()).toThrowError('getDefault products/offers api is deprecated')    
> 47 |     await expect(() => ProductsSdk.getDefault()).rejects.toThrow('getDefault products/offers api is deprecated');
     |                                                          ^
  48 |   })
  49 | })
  50 |
```

anyone got any idea how to fix ? code sample would be helpful
Thanks

Comment: Would need to await your function, like `expect(await ProductsSdk.getDefault()).rejects.toThrow('getDefault products/offers api is deprecated');`

Comment: Can't reproduce it. Need more details. What do `reImportSdk` and `configure` do?